# How to use Split tag

Tags: discussion, tags

This tag has cropped up.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/split

The first post was relating to org splits.

The next few were related to the Apex String.split() method.

Do we need a tag for a single method? IMO, this seems excessive.

In the context of salesforce, information about what happens during org splits could be relevant, but are there going to be that many questions in this forum about that?

Answer (score 4):

I'm in agreement Peter. I think `string` and `string-methods` sufficiently covers `split`. Splitting an Org as you say is a rare event and is something I'd expect Salesforce to likely be heavily involved in supporting. In my view, the tag should be merged with `string-methods`. At least I think that would be the proper way of handling it as opposed to using a synonym.

From quickly looking at questions tagged with `string`, it could be argued that the majority of those questions are also about `string-methods` as well. I don't know how many people that are currently active have sufficient votes/points on questions with those tags to vote on them. I have 8 in `string-methods` and only 4 in `string`. I believe it takes 5 to be eligible to vote for a synonym.

I don't know what it takes to do a merge. I'm confident one of our friendly moderators will pop in with an answer to that.

**Edit**

I now have the votes/points such that I've nominated `string-methods` as a synonym for the `string` tag. We now need 4 users with the votes/points who'll cast votes to approve it on the [synonyms page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms). That should at least help clean up that tag for us.

It appears will still waiting for a mod to appear from the Dreamforce haze to provide some insight on what a "merge" is. From the mouse-over, I got the sense it had something to do with a synonym being merged, but with "what" it was being merged was unclear to me. Is it another synonym or another tag entirely? I didn't see an answer to that question.

Comment: Is there an official merge feature? Or if there is, is it necessary with such a small set of tags? It is easy enough in this instance to simply apply the correct tag for the four posts that have arisen? I need to lookup and understand better what tag synonyms are.

Comment: I saw merge mentioned on the [Tag Synonyms Page](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) and didn't find anything further as to what it meant. Synonyms cause a retag of a post with the Synonym tag whenever any existing "child" tags are used that are considered to have equivalent meaning. Those tags don't disappear as choices, they just get automatically replaced. This is what happens when Exacttarget is selected by users & Marketing-Cloud magically appears in its place as the tag on the post.